# How to have multiple values for one key in hashtable from csv

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I tried to create an empty hashtable, import your CSV, group things by ID, then add each group to the hashtable.

But for some reason I am getting error:

```
Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Key cannot be null.
Parameter name: key"
At line:4 char:5
+     $myHT.add($_.Name,$_.Group.Name)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException
```

I have then tried the following which is much closer to my desired output:

```
$myCSV = Import-Csv "X:\Path\To\My\CSV\File.csv"
$myCSV | Group-Object -Property ID | Select-Object -Property @{N="ID";E={$_.Name}},@{N="Name";E={$_.Group.Name -join ","}}
```

However, if I still have duplicates if I have the same name with the same ID in my csv. Is there anyway to get unique names only?
I currently get the following:

```
ID    Name
1234  John, John, Jeff
1235  Jane
1236  Bob
```

I only want the name to be added once if it already exists.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a hashtable, then the easiest way would be to make an empty one, import your CSV, group things by ID, then add each group to the hashtable.

```
$myHT = @{}
$myCSV = Import-Csv "X:\Path\To\My\CSV\File.csv"
$myCSV | Group ID | ForEach-Object {
    $myHT.add($_.Name,$_.Group.Name)
}
```

That won't put a pretty ', ' between names, but each key in the hashtable will have a value that's an array of names.

Comment: For some reason when i try this method i get an error. However, I have been playing around and found another way that gets closer to my desired output but still not quite. I have edited the question so you can see the changes above.

Comment: I've figure it out, posted the answer below

Answer (score 0):

You need to de-dupe the `$_.Group.Name` items using another `Select-Object` or `Sort-Object` like below:

Using your example csv:

> ```
> ID,Name
> 1234,John
> 1235,Jane
> 1236,Bob
> 1234,Jeff
> ```

```
$myCSV = Import-Csv "D:\test\input.csv" | Group-Object -Property ID | 
    Select-Object @{Name = "ID";   Expression = {$_.Name}},
                  @{Name = "Name"; Expression = {($_.Group.Name | Select-Object -Unique) -join ","}}

$myCSV
```

Output:

> ```
> ID   Name     
> --   ----     
> 1234 John,Jeff
> 1235 Jane     
> 1236 Bob
> ```

Comment: My 'Name' Column is empty. It is only showing the ID column

Comment: @A.Codes Please have a look at the edited code. I have included the sample CSV. Does your CSV file look the same? Does it use a different separater character maybe?

Comment: I figured it out, posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out. You can use Group-Object with some calculated properties to get the desired output.

```
$myCSV = Import-Csv "X:\Path\To\My\CSV\File.csv"
$myCSV | Select-Object -Property ID,Name -Unique | Group-Object -Property ID | Select-Object -Property @{N="ID";E={$_.Name}},@{N="Name";E={$_.Group.Name -join ","}}
```